# Making an element draggable?

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to make an element draggable, like so:

```
var element = $("<li id='test'>Hello</li>");
element.appendTo("#panelParent");
element.draggable("enable");
element.draggable("option", "connectToSortable", '#panelTarget');
element.draggable("option", "helper", 'clone');
element.draggable("option", "revert", 'invalid');
```

nothing happens when I try dragging this element. It works fine though if I embed the object in the page beforehand instead of trying to dynamically create the element. Any idea what I'm missing? For example, this works:

```
$(function() {
    $("#test").draggable({
        connectToSortable: '#panelTarget',
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid'
     });
});

<ul>
  <li id='test'>Hello</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oh actually the call should be:

```
element.draggable();
```

not:

```
element.draggable("enable");
```

maybe I'm reading the docs wrong, it does say:

```
.draggable( "enable" )
```

?

Thanks

Comment: It works now? `.draggable("enable")` might be a setting method, that is, a method that only works after the draggable has been created (using `.draggable()`).